# R - Import html/json map file to use for heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth

I'm trying to upload a U.S. DMA map into R to create heatmamps. I've found ggplot and [choroplehyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethr/vignettes/c-county-choropleth.html) packages to be helpful in the mapping part, but don't know how to import my own maps to use. [This](https://gist.github.com/simzou/6459889#file-nielsentopo-json) is the DMA map I found online, how would I go about importing it?

I also assume that after uploading, I will need to create my own DMA_choropleth in order to color the DMA regions based on population, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most certainly do *not* need to install the `geojsonio` package. It's a great package, but uses `rgdal` to do the hard work. This gets you the map and the data without relying on a special choropleth pkg.

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
library(ggthemes)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(viridis)
library(scales)

neil <- readOGR("nielsentopo.json", "nielsen_dma", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
                verbose=FALSE)
# there are some techincal problems with the polygon that D3 glosses over
neil <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(gBuffer(neil, byid=TRUE, width=0),
                                  data=neil@data)
neil_map <- fortify(neil, region="id")

tv <- fromJSON("tv.json", flatten=TRUE)
tv_df <- map_df(tv, as.data.frame, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, .id="id")
colnames(tv_df) <- c("id", "rank", "dma", "tv_homes_count", "pct", "dma_code")
tv_df$pct <- as.numeric(tv_df$pct)/100

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=neil_map, map=neil_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    color="white", size=0.05, fill=NA)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=tv_df, map=neil_map,
                    aes(fill=pct, map_id=id),
                    color="white", size=0.05)
gg <- gg + scale_fill_viridis(name="% US", labels=percent)
gg <- gg + coord_proj(paste0("+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96",
                             " +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"))
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="bottom")
gg <- gg + theme(legend.key.width=unit(2, "cm"))
gg
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason the fortify() doesn't work.  It doesn't 'like' the region = 'id' argument.  Can you help?

Comment: I'm given back this error: Too few points in geometry component at or near point -82.061259930000006 26.499350110000002Ring Self-intersection at or near point -89.1404651 29.135150639999999Ring Self-intersection at or near point -78.518767870000005 33.867667130000001SpP is invalid
Invalid objects found; consider using set_RGEOS_CheckValidity(2L)Error in rgeos::gUnaryUnion(spgeom = SpP, id = IDs) : 
  TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point -78.518767870000005 33.867667130000001 at -78.518767870000005 33.867667130000001

Comment: rgdal is deprecated and will no longer be available at the end of 2023. How would you do this in 2024?

Answer (score 2):

The DMA map you found ("nielsentopo.json") is in topojson format. To import it as a spatial object that can be mapped, you need to install the geojsonio package. Here's annotated code to install the package, read the json map, convert it into a dataframe, and plot it. In order to color the DMA regions on this map -yes, you'll need to create your own choropleth class (useful: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethr/vignettes/h-creating-your-own-maps.html ).

```
# Package 'geojsonio' installation notes:

# If are a Mac user, first install package gdal using homebrew (open system terminal, type "brew install gdal")
# Then install any required R packages you don't already have:
# install.packages("rgdal", type = "source", configure.args = "--with-gdal-config=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/unix/bin/gdal-config --with-proj-include=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/include --with-proj-lib=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/lib")
# install.packages("rgeos", type = "source")

# If are a Linux user, first install required libraries (open system terminal, type "sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev libgdal-dev libgeos-c1v5 libproj-dev libv8-dev")
# Then install any required R packages you don't already have:
# install.packages("rgdal", type = "source")
# install.packages("rgeos", type = "source")

# If you are a Windows user, no preliminary steps are necessary


# Install package geojsonio
install.packages("geojsonio")


# Load required packages
library(geojsonio)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(jsonlite)


# Read topjson file
myMap <- topojson_read("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/simzou/6459889/raw/fd1cf20e3a9714982bfcedbd5b2117fead27a1bf/nielsentopo.json")

#Convert spatial object myMap into a dataframe so it can be plotted
myMapDF <- fortify(myMap)

# Basic map  plot
ggplot(data = myMapDF, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "white")
```

Once imported, your map looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copy the tv.json from the website to disk and then read it:

```
df = data.frame(fromJSON("c:\\tv.json"))
```

You'll get a dataframe with 1050 rows.