# Having trouble reading a topojson into R for plotting using ggplot2 and sp

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, r-sp, topojson

I'm trying to read a topojson into R for ggplot2 use. It seems the `rgdal` package is being retired, so I'm trying to use `st_read` in the `sp` package, but I just get a big box and that's all. It looks like the fields I get are about right, but it's definitely not getting the whole thing in there correctly. It says it only has one feature and two fields. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks.

I tried following these directions, but nothing seemed to work:

[R - Import html/json map file to use for heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493585/r-import-html-json-map-file-to-use-for-heatmap)
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/09/overcoming-d3-cartographic-envy-with-r-ggplot/

I can give an example file---I know it works, because we do use it and are able to show it with D3, but I want to be able to show it using ggplot2.

Example code that doesn't work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)

j <- sf::st_read("mytopo.json")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = iso_a3), j) +
  coord_sf()

j <- geojsonio::topojson_read("mytopo.json")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = iso_a3), j) +
  coord_sf()
```

Note: Deleted the link to the example for security reasons.

Comment: I have two comments: 1) st_read actualy lives in sf, not sp (no big deal...) 2) the topojson linked as "mytopo.json" seems to be malformed. Are you 100% certain it follows the standards?

Comment: Right, all these 2 letter package names that I'm not that familiar with---oops. As to the file being malformed, it may be. What I know is that with other software I can look at it.

Comment: So for example, I can read it with mapshaper.com.

Comment: you can try reading it with any kind of a GIS software - the QGIS comes to my mind... when I open your topojson in qgis I get the same rectangle as in ggplot + in addition the strange rectangle has extent from 0 to 940 in x axis and 0 to 470 in y axis - which does not comply with GeoJSON specs, which ask for lat long

Comment: on second thought: the GeoJSON specs are long-lat, not lat-long; an easy mistake to make (EPSG:4326 is lat long) - but the fact remains that since your file contains coordinate values higher than 180 it is unlikely to comply with https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-4

Comment: Well, if that's the case, do we just have to give up? Or is there a way to make it work? Because I can definitely open it with other software (I haven't tried QGIS, but it does work with mapshaper). I think it's clearly more than just out of bound points, because it's only picking up one feature, and obviously there are ~200.

Comment: What is the source of the file? I don't think it originated in mapshaper. Is could be that a raw version of the file could be better readable... But there seems not to be much that can be done with the file as it stands now

Comment: No, it didn't come from mapshaper. It is a cartogram, made by a private company. I have a lot of them like this. But this is the original file---there's nothing else.

Comment: Looks like you can get it into R for ggplot2, but you have to open in at mapshaper.org and export it as a shapefile. There are some problems with geometries, so casting to 'MULTILINESTRING' is necessary too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files can be opened in R with some help from [mapshaper.org](https://mapshaper.org/). I used the online upload, but there's a [command line tool](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Introduction-to-the-Command-Line-Tool) as well.

Use mapshaper to export the file as a shapefile.  There might be some options to correct the geometries that R has a hard time with, but I'm unfamiliar with mapshaper & it's options.  The code below takes care of the problem of invalid geometries pretty well in R.  Once converted by mapshaper, you'll have a folder with .dbf, .shp, and .shx files that R's `sf` package can read.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

my_sf <- st_read('path/to/shapefile/folder/')
#> Reading layer `00005f8d4076b8ced__' from data source `path/to/shapefile/folder/' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 218 features and 1 field (with 3 geometries empty)
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 940 ymax: 470
#> CRS:           NA

# But some geometries are not valid (only showing first 3 rows)
st_is_valid(my_sf[1:3,])
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE

# Fixing the invalid geometries taken from:
#  https://r-spatial.org/r/2017/03/19/invalid.html#making-invalid-polygons-valid

valid <- st_is_valid(my_sf)
my_sf_valid <- st_buffer(my_sf[!is.na(valid),], 0.0)

ggplot(my_sf_valid) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

The cartogram shows up but is flipped. There's a gis stack question about that here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/233792/161721

It may have something to do with mapshaper flipping coordinates for .svg/topojson files

> width= (SVG/TopoJSON) Set the width of the output dataset in pixels. When used with TopoJSON output, this option switches the output coordinates from geographic units to pixels and flips the Y axis. SVG output is always in pixels (default SVG width is 800).

Above quote from: https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference

<sup>Created on 2022-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>